# File Cannot be Read: UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I have a 'csv' file that contains columns of str, int, and datetime. When I open the file using `pd.read_csv(file_name, encoding='utf-8')`, I get the following errors:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position
>   109: invalid start byte

I tried using the code below but I get a 'str' type outcome of all of my columns, each value separated by a comma.

```
file = open(file_name, "r", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
df = file.read()
```

How do I read the file as a dataframe or transform the outcome of the code above into a dataframe?

Comment: Try changing the encoding to let's say latin-1. If not to another one.

Comment: Incidentally, 0xa5 is the yen sign ¥.

Comment: try to read as bytes first then try to decode with `latin-1` `utf-8` etc

Comment: As I understand it, OP second example reading in as utf-8 worked fine as he got a str of the csv line. So I doubt this is a wrong encoding issue, but so far as I can tell the pd.read_csv syntax for the encoding is correct...so definitely odd.

Comment: Why would the data not be string? There's no parsing being requested in the read command? Seems like Pandas should be used here to read and parse the strings

Answer (score 0):

The data is not UTF-8-encoded if you get a UnicodeDecode error.

You haven't provided any sample data, but to load a simple file like:

```
filename,integer,date
file,1,2018-02-02
```

This can be used to get data types other than string (disclaimer, not a pandas expert (yet)...just read the docs.  There's probably a more simple way to parse dates):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a=pd.read_csv('out.csv',dtype={1:int},converters={2:lambda x:datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d')})
>>> a
  filename  integer       date
0     file        1 2018-02-02
>>> a.dtypes
filename            object
integer              int32
date        datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```